# Why am i getting a ClassCastException in this recursive function

Tags: recursion, clojure

I've written a recursive function to get a total cost of a journey. 
costOfPath simply makes a call to ubergraph to get the cost for each journey, then this function adds them and displays it.

```
(defn routeCost [parcel cost]
 "Calculate the total route cost"
  (if (empty? parcel)
  (print "Total Journey Cost: " cost)
     ((def first-parcel (first parcel))
    (def start (:start first-parcel))                       
     (def finish (:finish first-parcel))  
  (def value (costOfPath start finish))
   (def parcel-two (rest parcel))
   (routeCost parcel-two (+ cost value)))))

(routeCost task8 0)
```

Task 8 looks as such:

```
(def task8 [(Parcel. :main-office :r131 "Plastic Wallets" "Delivery" 1)
            (Parcel. :r131 :r111 "CDs" "Delivery" 1)
            (Parcel. :r111 :r121 "USBs" "Collection" 2)
            (Parcel. :r121 :main-office "USBs" "Delivery" 2)])
```

The function prints out the correct cost, but gives a classCastException.

```
ClassCastException practice_ubergraph.core.Parcel cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  clojure.lang.Var.fn (Var.java:363)
```

The parcel record:

```
(defrecord Parcel [start            
                   finish
                   package 
                   run-type
                   weight
                   ])
```

Why is this happening and how can i stop it?

EDIT: I think its something to do with the IF statement and the way i've put the brackets around the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tony says, it's a good idea to try to limit your use of `def`s to the top level.

The reason you see a `ClassCastException` is probably this line:

```
((def first-parcel (first parcel))
```

You're defining `first-parcel` and then calling it immediately with the outer set of parentheseis.

Compare it to this example which generates a similar exception:

```
((def a 1))
```

In this example `a` gets the value `1`. `def` returns the var `#'user/a`, so the expression that is evaluated is:

```
(#'user/a)
```

The value of `#'user/a` is `1`, and `1` is then treated as a function.

Generally, if you see `cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn` look for a double set of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Please do NOT use def in a function.
Here is a much better one

`(defn route-cost [parcel cost]
  "Calculate the total route cost"
  (if (empty? parcel)
    (print "Total Journey Cost: " cost)
    (let [{:keys [start finish]} (first parcel)
          value (cost-of-path start finish)]
      (route-cost (rest parcel) (+ cost value)))))`

The essence of clojure is that  you could write your code as concise as possible .  usually we use kebab-case in clojure to differentiate Java

Use let in your function will fix everything